# Can't solve MongoParseError: Invalid connection string

Tags: mongodb, docker, mongoose, docker-compose

I'm not able to solve MongoParseError.

First I had tried this

```
mongoose.connect(`mongodb://${process.env.DB_USER}:${process.env.DB_PASSWORD}@db:27017/${process.env.DB_NAME}`, {useNewUrlParser: true});
```

made me ending up in this error

```
MongoParseError: Unescaped slash in userinfo section
```

Then I escaped all the slashes

```
mongoose.connect(`mongodb:\\/\\/${process.env.DB_USER}:${process.env.DB_PASSWORD}@db:27017\\/${process.env.DB_NAME}`, {useNewUrlParser: true});
```

and I ended up in this error which I'm not able to solve

```
MongoParseError: Invalid connection string
```

This is my index.js

```
'use strict';

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect(`mongodb:\\/\\/${process.env.DB_USER}:${process.env.DB_PASSWORD}@db:27017\\/${process.env.DB_NAME}`, {useNewUrlParser: true});

var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function() {
  console.log('ok');
});

const express = require('express');

// Constants
const PORT = 8080;
const HOST = 'localhost';


var kittySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String
});

var Kitten = mongoose.model('Kitten', kittySchema);

var silence = new Kitten({ name: 'Test1234' });


// App
const app = express();
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send(silence.name);
});

app.listen(PORT);
console.log(`Running on http://${HOST}:${PORT}`);
```

And here's the docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: npm start
    volumes:
      - ./src:/usr/app/
      - ./src/node_modules:/usr/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - 80:8080
    environment:
      DB_NAME: websitedb
      DB_USER: /run/secrets/db_user
      DB_PASSWORD: /run/secrets/db_password
    secrets:
      - db_user
      - db_password
  db:
    image: mongo:latest
    volumes:
      - ./mongo-init.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.js:ro
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: websitedb
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME_FILE: /run/secrets/db_user
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/db_password
    secrets:
      - db_user
      - db_password
volumes:
  mongo:
secrets:
  db_user:
    file: ./db_user.txt
  db_password:
    file: ./db_password.txt
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What are the contents of `./db_user.txt` and `./db_password.txt`? Any slashes in there?

Comment: I don't have any special characters in these two files.

Comment: If the username or password includes `@`, `:`, `/`, or `%` use [percent encoding](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-2.1)

Comment: The above comment solved for me (I had a / in the password). To apply the encoding you can use the encodeURIComponent().

Answer (score 2):

Looking through the [guide on managing secrets in docker compose](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/#use-secrets-in-compose), it looks like any secrets are passed into the container as a file mounted in `/run/secrets/SECRET_NAME`, and the suggestion is to pass the path to this file as an environment variable and then read the file in your app:

> When you deploy, Docker mounts a file under /run/secrets/ in the services. These files are never persisted in disk, but are managed in memory.
>
> Each service uses environment variables to specify where the service should look for that secret data.

You have passed the path to these secrets as `process.env.DB_USER`, but to get the actual secret you need to read the file:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

let dbUser = fs.readFileSync(process.env.DB_USER);
let dbPassword = fs.readFileSync(process.env.DB_PASSWORD);

mongoose.connect(`mongodb://${dbUser}:${dbPassword}@db:27017/${process.env.DB_NAME}`, {useNewUrlParser: true});
```